# Uploading to App Store from a multi-app build

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project with 6 targets. They generate almost-identical iOS apps. I almost always build and upload them together.

I'm trying to simplify that flow somewhat. I've put together a schema that builds all six targets. When I build and archive that schema, I get a line in the Archive window under the schema name, as opposed to individual apps; the "Upload to App Store" button is grayed out on that line. There's "Export", but it doesn't produce IPAs.

Tried a similar approach with a target that lists the 6 apps as dependencies and a schema over that target - same result.

A most welcome side effect of a multi-app build is that common dependency libraries are only built once, not six times over. Time saving is considerable, so I would hate to go back to six separate builds.

Question: what's the right way to build multiple iOS apps in one go? If a multi-target schema is the answer, how can I get them to App Store?

Comment: I'm quite sure that fastlane can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IPA can be trivially built from an app bundle - just place the bundle into a folder called "Payload" and zip it up. Application Loader will happily submit said IPA to the App Store.

Some claim you can upload via command line, too, but I haven't tried yet. App Loader works.

You can even make preparing the IPAs a part of the build, by providing a post-archival script step in schema properties.

The following shell script will get to the archived products:

```
Today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
XCArc=~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/$Today
ArcName=`ls -t $XCArc | head -n 1`
XCArc=$XCArc/$ArcName/Products/Applications

cd $TEMP
mkdir Payload
cp -r $XCArc/MyApp.app Payload/
zip -r -y -q -9 MyApp.ipa Payload
```

This picks up the latest archived build from the Xcode archives and makes an IPA under $TEMP.